# parametrized surface are isometric if all corresponding curves have same length

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

A pair of parametrized surface are isometric if and only if  all corresponding curves have same length.

I have proved one direction, unable to prove the direction a pair of parametrized surface are isometric if all corresponding curves have same length.

Comment: Your question could be made clearer - introduce notation for the surfaces and the "correspondence" between them. The idea of the proof here should be to differentiate: if $\gamma_s$ denotes the restriction of some curve $\gamma$ to the interval $[0,s]$, then you can differentiate $s \mapsto L(\gamma_s)$ to find $|\dot \gamma(0)|.$

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have a diffeomorphism between the two spaces (otherwise what does *corresponding* mean).

It would be true if the distance from $p $ to $q $ is the infimum of the distances of all curves from  $p $ to $q $...  but I believe this is true. ..